# Write log when Composer doesn't find the class

Tags: php, class, logging, composer-php

I want to ask you some help today because I wanted to create a log file error when an autoload class with Composer fails. I succeeded in it by writing it directly in the ClassLoader.php, but each time I update Composer, all is erased. I have no idea of where to put it :

Here is the part of my work :

In ClassLoader.php, findFile method :

```
    if (false === $file) {
        // Remember that this class does not exist.
        $this->missingClasses[$class] = true;
        ob_start();
        echo date("d/m/Y H:i:s") . "\n";
        debug_print_backtrace();
        $trace = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        file_put_contents(FILEPATH_CLASS_EXCEPTION, $trace, FILE_APPEND);
    }
```

With it, it works, but where can I add it without changing the source code?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using any frameworks or component classes / libraries?

Comment: Don't modify composers files. You should make an error handler that handles that stuff. You could also use some tried and tested library like [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog). Then you will be able to log all errors (which you probably want anyway since it doesn't make sense just to log some errors).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [composer-plugin](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/plugins.md) that replaces the autoload generator with a wrapper providing an extension with your desired functionality. Then you can make that plugin a dependency of the package you want the logging functionality within.